# android:How can I output video from my android phone to a HDTV via HDMI ports?

Tags: android

i am new to android.my project name is ANDROMODA. How can I output video from my android phone to  any display screens either LCD/HDTV.is there any HDMI API for android developers to do this activity.pls send the response as early as possible.thanks in advance.
and also if u KNOW any one pls tell me the High level design for Androidproject.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for that but the good news is that once an HDMI is plugged in, the screen is automatically displayed to the TV.  So it's an automatic thing no matter what app is running.  If I understood correctly this should answer your question?